# How to prevent PDC Task Client: Maintenance Scheduler from waking up the computer?

Tags: windows, windows-11

My computer is a Windows 11 laptop and suddenly it wakes up from suspension.

When I run the `command powercfg /systempowerreport /duration 1`, I can see that the cause for it is PDC Task Client: Maintenance Scheduler as of below:

[image]

But I got no scheduled maitenance on my computer. Anyone got a clue how to prevent that scheduler from waking up my laptop?

Comment: Experiencing the same problem on a laptop.  Did you ever manage to fix it?

Comment: I am also having this problem and cannot find any solution on a brand new Intel NUC Windows 11

Comment: Please run in an elevated CMD the command `powercfg.exe /sleepstudy` and upload online the resulting `.html` file.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, too.
Let me to help you specify and solve this issue.

The problem has a brilliant solution.

First of all I recommend you to create familiar with the power management system which you can do in elevated Windows command line.

These two commands will create an HTML file which you can open in your web browser.

```
powercfg /sleepstudy /xml
powercfg /sleepstudy /transformxml sleepstudy-report.xml
```

You can create a bat file and for later analysis you can launch this bat file as administrator.

If you open the created file `sleepstudy-report.html`, you should be able to quickly orient yourself. At the bottom of the file is the newest power management activity. All of this is very comfortable to view and you can unfold or fold all the objects in this view for more details about particular records.

Very useful is the **Start Time, Duration, State, Entry Reason, Exit Reason** where you can get an overview of the power management during a particular time period.

Now to the Entry reason you mentioned: **PDC Task Client: Maintenance Scheduler**

This one reason of wake up your computer/laptop is the more complicated to catch, but it can be done. The answer is to look for built the value in Windows GUI settings and not in Task Scheduler.

My last wakeup from the same reason as is the subject of this thread was at a 3am clock and I can see this statement on the attached screenshot below.

[image: Maintenance control panel view in Windows]

[image: Generated view to html power management overview]

The picture is showing that all is happening here: ***Control Panel\System and Security\Security and Maintenance***

Now. When you can change your settings, set the value to some particular time of day and you device will able to sleep in one time block.

Update 1:
One question - Scheduler task - discovered. It is responsible for waking up my device at a night time despite the fact that the wake up is forbidden in the task and also in the power plan.

I used powershell to list the task. (You can use GUI to open the task for sure)

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-ScheduledTask | where{$_.TaskPath -eq "\Microsoft\Windows\Security\PwdLess\"} | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo


LastRunTime        : 18.01.2024 3:00:00
LastTaskResult     : 0
NextRunTime        : 19.01.2024 3:00:00
NumberOfMissedRuns : 0
TaskName           : IntelligentPwdlessTask
TaskPath           : \Microsoft\Windows\Security\Pwdless\
PSComputerName     :
```

You can change the time to whatever you like. For this change you are supposed to have super user permissions. To get these permissions can help application named PowerRun which help you to launch Windows Task Scheduler from inside this program.
You can free download this program here:
https://www.sordum.org/9416/powerrun-v1-6-run-with-highest-privileges/

After you change the time, I hope now your laptop/notebook will sleep like a baby without the disturbances of the modern standby sleep state. My device did.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing this same issue, the solutions may be different for each device due to drivers, devices and other components. You can run a trace against the PDC Task Client (Power Dependency Coordinator) via the following [MS Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/modern-standby-resume-performance). This will hopefully provide you the details you need to discover the process causing the wake-from-sleep.

> To evaluate connected standby resume performance, take a trace with the provider named Microsoft-Windows-PDC, which is the system-supplied power dependency coordinator. The Trace_start.cmd file that is included with the WPA package includes this and other providers that are required to measure resume performance. The WPA package is available in the Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit (Windows ADK) download and includes scripts and documentation for modern standby analysis.

(From the above article)To collect a trace

- Open a Command Prompt window as Administrator.
- Run the Install.cmd command to install the package.
- Follow the instructions in Capture a WPA trace to collect the trace.
- For validating resume performance, a 5-10 minute session should be sufficient.
- To save the trace file, rename it or save it to a different location because a file with this name will be overwritten the next time a trace is taken.
- Repeat steps 3-4 to gather another trace.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I have tried running a trace but I don't know what I am supposed to be learning from it or how to fix the problem. Can you clarify in more detail or explain what you did to solve yours if you were able to? This is driving me crazy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The command to check last wake up is:

```
powercfg /lastwake
```

Then there is chance that you can turn that wake up off by:

`Control Panel`-`Power options`-change current plan options-`Change advanced`-`Sleep`-`Resume by scheduler`-`turn off`.

Also in this window you have other options when to wake up computer, so change accordingly.